# Replace words in column when search a word from another file is match

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

File 1

```
 rta a xxx
 qqq b qqq
 rta c xxx
 qqq d qqq
```

File 2

```
qwe d vzc
wex c xcz
vfx b cvz
vcv a asd
```

The output I want in File 2

```
 qqq d qqq
 rta c xxx
 qqq b qqq
 rta a xxx
```

i need to try the match a certain word like column two and replace the words in column one and column two based on the words search .

Comment: What you had tried so far ?

Comment: i try use the grep 
grep ‘a'  File2 | sed 's/vcv/qqq/'

Comment: but this command take a  lot of time if i want to compare many characters to replace,any faster ways to just auto search and replace the words

Answer (score 0):

If order in result is no matter:

```
grep -Fwf <(tr -s ' ' '\t' <file2|cut -f2) file1
```

Comment: thank you ,i use grep aslo but different command from u